# Assign row number per ID, where certain values always have fixed numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a query that assigns row numbers per ID in a database table, and certain specific values always get fixed row numbers. For instance, if the value in `col2` is `A`, then the row number should be consistently set to `1`. Similarly, if `col2` contains the value `B`, then the row number should always be `2`. All other values in `col2` should be assigned row numbers in consecutive order starting from `3`.

Desired result:

```
myid    col1    col2    row_number
----------------------------------
1       foo     A       1
1       bar     B       2
1       foobar  C       3
1       foobar  D       4   
2       foobar  A       1
2       foob    X       3
3       hello   B       2
3       hello   Z       3
3       hi      Y       4
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cW0Ftu6i) is an example which is not working properly.

Comment: you are missing an order column, which determines that A is 1  and why i c and x 3, should they have different numbers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to start the `row_number` with a specific offset, ignoring constant values and assigning them a constant row number.

You can do something a bit ugly like this:

```
SELECT myid, col1, col2,
        case
          when col2 = 'A' then 1
          when col2 = 'B' then 2
         else row_number() over (partition by myid
                                 order by case when col2 = 'A' then 'ZZZ'
                                               when col2 = 'B' then 'ZZZ1'
                                               else col2
                                           end)  + 2
       end as row_number   
FROM  newtable
ORDER BY myid, row_number
```

Result:

```
MYID    COL1    COL2    ROW_NUMBER
1        foo     A           1
1        bar     B           2
1        foobar  C           3
1        foobar  D           4
2        foobar  A           1
2        foob    X           3
3        hello   B           2
3        hello   Y           3
3        hello   Z           4
```

This start the row number from +2 (Depending on the number of constant values [A,B]), giving each constant value a value that will be sorted last in the `row_number` window function so the rest will be sorted first.